# Child_of not displaying all children posts.. via get_posts

Tags: posts, categories, loop

I have put together this loop to display all children posts of the desired cat, but i am not getting any of the posts from one of the children cats..
Not sure if i am using the best method to accomplish what I am trying to do..

```
 <?php
        $posts = array();
         $categories = get_categories('child_of=5');
         foreach($categories as $category) {
           $args=array(
            'post_per_page' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'numberposts' => 45,
            'category__in' => array($category->term_id)             
           );
         $posts = $posts + get_posts($args);
        } // Close your foreach here
             shuffle($posts);
              if ($posts) {
                foreach($posts as $post) {
                  setup_postdata($post);
                   ?>
                    <div <?php post_class('boxy');?>><div  class="soc-label" ></div>

                  <?php 
                      if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                      $full_image_url =    wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
                      echo '<a href="' . $full_image_url[0] . '" rel="lightbox" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
                      the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                      echo '</a>';
                    }
                   ?>

                    <?php the_content(''); ?>
                    </div>


        <?php } 
           } 

        ?>
```

I am using the results in a tiled mosaic of sorts with Isotope, and I am shuffling the results, thats also a must..
Any guidance would be appreciated I have spend the last couple weeks getting as far as I am now.

Comment: Do you mean to have `posts_per_page` set to 5?

Comment: I've been trying many things to get the desired results..  I am looking to have the most recent 5 posts from each child cat.

Comment: Is it just one category that isn't working? If so, does it happen to be a "grandchild" category?

Comment: yes just one cat, and no its a child not a grandchild..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach is way wrong. Try combining the category ids in an array, then running one query only to get the posts you want.

Edit: read your comments. Try use using an array function like array_merge instead of the + to combine the resulting post arrays. See if that helps.

Comment: Otto, thanks for the input. I am a beginner/novice at best with PHP..  I have put the code here together from research, not sure how to put the logic I'm trying to achieve together correctly..

Comment: Otto,  I made a couple small changes with your input and was able to get the result I was looking for, Thank you! '

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to get it working using array_merge()..
Here is the code..  still might have a couple code errors but its working.

```
    <?php
        $posts = array();
         $categories = get_categories('child_of=4');
         foreach($categories as $category) {
           $args=array(         
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'numberposts' => 40,
            'category__in' => array($category->term_id)             
           );
         $posts = array_merge($posts,get_posts($args));
        } // Close your foreach here
             shuffle($posts);
              if ($posts) {
                foreach($posts as $post) {
                  setup_postdata($post);
                   ?>
                    <div <?php post_class('boxy');?>><div class="soc-label" ></div>

                  <?php 
                      if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                      $full_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
                      echo '<a href="' . $full_image_url[0] . '" rel="lightbox" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
                      the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                      echo '</a>';
                    }
                   ?>

                    <?php the_content(''); ?>
                    </div>


        <?php } 
           } 

        ?>
```